# When adding item to cart go to cart page shopify

Tags: html, e-commerce, shopify

I am trying to add a product from the product page in shopify and then go directly to the cart. I cannot do this for some reason I have tried surrounding it with anchor tags and hrefs but nothing works. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to alter your add to cart code so that you add the product and then go the cart on success. The [Shopify AJAX API](https://docs.shopify.com/themes/development/getting-started/using-ajax-api) page shows a simple example.

```
jQuery.post('/cart/add.js', $('form[action="/cart/add"]').serialize());
```

If you want to test success then something like:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url:'/cart/add.js', 
    dataType:'json', 
    method:'POST', 
    data:$('form[action="/cart/add"]').serialize()}).
done(function(jR){
   if(jR.status) alert(jR.message);
   else location.href = '/cart';
});
```